# Visual Studio 2010 Debugging problem Tool tip code inspector

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

When debugging in VS I step through the code but the when I move my mouse over variables and properties it shows nothing.

For example:

[image: Debug example]

If I hover my mouse over StoreId it should display the value. It doesn't though, however, if I I hover my mouse over myStore it displays the above?

It's like it cant map the properties to the object in run time.

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check that you haven't enabled any optimizations in the build options.

Optimizations can lead to whole variables being removed from compiled code, instructions being executed in a different order than initially expected...

Answer (score 0):

This problem was addressed in the SP1 release of VS2O10, did you install it?